# React Google Map Marker Not cenetered

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, redux, react-google-maps

I am trying to get the map to be centered to the defaultMarker. However, when the map finish loading the view was slightly above the default marker. I have to scroll down to the middle to see the defaultMarker. 
Any idea how I can center the view when the map is loaded? I am using React, redux, and react-google-maps.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker} from "react-google-maps";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class VenuesMap extends Component {

  render() {

        let markers;
        if (this.props.venues !== null) {
            markers = this.props.venues.map((venue, i) => {
                return (
                    <Marker
                        key={i}
                        position={{ lat: venue.location.lat, lng: venue.location.lng}}
                    />
                )
            })
        } else {
            markers = <Marker position={{ lat: 40.7589, lng:-73.9851}}/>
        }
const MapWithAMarker = withGoogleMap(props =>
  <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.7589, lng: -73.9851 }}
        center={{ lat: 40.7589, lng: -73.9851 }}
        zoom={15}
  >
    {markers}
  </GoogleMap>
);
        const googleMap =   <MapWithAMarker
            containerElement={<div style={{
                                height: `410vh`
            }} />}
            mapElement={<div style={{ height: `410vh`
             }} />}
        />
    return (
            <div>
                {googleMap}
            </div>
        )
  }
}

const stateToProps = (state) => {
  return {venues: state.venue.venues}
}

export default connect(stateToProps)(VenuesMap)
```

[image: When the map starts it is above the default Marker]
[image: I have to scroll down]

Comment: why `height: 410vh`? maximum window height is `100vh`.

Comment: You are right! It worked. THANKS MUCH!

Comment: I've added the answer to the answers list below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maximum window height is `100vh`.

just try `height: 100vh` or less.